# Plotting a 3D Cylindrical Surface plot in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, 3d, surface

I am trying to create a cylindrical 3D surface plot using Python, where my independent variables are `z` and `theta`, and the dependent variable is `radius` (i.e., `radius` is a function of vertical position and azimuth angle).
So far, I have only been able to find ways to create a 3D surface plot that:

- has `z` as a function of `r` and `theta`
- has `r` as a function of `z`, but does not change with `theta` (so, the end product looks like a revolved contour; for example, the case of `r = sin(z) + 1` ).

I would like to have `r` as a function of `z` **and** `theta`, because my function will produce a shape that, at any given height, will be a complex function of `theta`.
On top of that, I need the surface plot be able to have (but does **not** have to have, depending on the properties of the function) an open top or bottom. For example, if `r` is constant from `z = 0` to `z = 1` (a perfect cylinder), I would want a surface plot that would only consist of the side of the cylinder, not the top or bottom. The plot should look like a hollow shell.

I already have the function `r` defined.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, after some trial and error, the best/easiest thing to do in this case is to just to convert the `r`, `theta`, and `z` data points (defined as 2D arrays, just like for an `x,y,z` plot) into cartesian coordinates:

```
# convert to rectangular
x = r*numpy.cos(theta)
y = r*numpy.sin(theta)
z = z
```

The new `x,y,z` arrays can be plotted just like any other `x,y,z` arrays generated from a polynomial where `z` is a function of `x,y`.  I had originally thought that the data points would get screwed up because of overlapping `z` values or maybe the adjacent data points would not be connected correctly, but apparently that is not the case.